# Jenkins build with gradle does not produce a apk file into build artifacts

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins build with gradle does not produce a apk file into build artifacts, it returns specified files and folders in that folder in workspace but not generate apk file.

Here is console log, build artifacts and config.[image]
Basically Build is successful but its not updating build artifacts with updated apk.

Problem is apk is not updated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with console log?

Comment: Build is successful there is no error found in console log.

Comment: I just want to see the command and output from gradle.

Comment: Why ask the question if you won't provide necessary info like the console output, or the job config — in particular the "archive the artifacts" config?